# How can I use DocumentFragment to speed up this code?

Tags: javascript

I just learned about `DocumentFragment`, but I'm not entirely sure how to use it with what I have so far. I have around 9K-10K rows in my table and it takes about 4 seconds to load the entire table.

```
for (const user of totalsArray)
{
    const truncatedUsername = truncateUsername(user);

    const newRow = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);

    const newCell0 = newRow.insertCell(USERNAME_IDX);
    const newCell1 = newRow.insertCell(TOTAL_COMMENTS_IDX);
    const newCell2 = newRow.insertCell(TOTAL_SCORE_IDX);
    const newCell3 = newRow.insertCell(TOTAL_NEG_COMMENTS_IDX);

    const userName = document.createTextNode(truncatedUsername);
    const totalComments = document.createTextNode(user[TOTAL_COMMENTS_IDX]);
    const totalScore = document.createTextNode(user[TOTAL_SCORE_IDX]);
    const totalNegatives = document.createTextNode(user[TOTAL_NEG_COMMENTS_IDX]);

    newCell0.appendChild(userName)
    newCell1.appendChild(totalComments);
    newCell2.appendChild(totalScore);
    newCell3.appendChild(totalNegatives);
}
```

From what I understand, you make the new fragment with `new DocumentFragment()`, then you append to it instead of the DOM, then when you are done with the main loop, you append the fragment to the DOM. But I am not seeing a way to do that with the way I am currently inserting cells into the row, and then appending a new text node to each cell. How does `DocumentFragment` fit in here?

Comment: You'd use a fragment for the entire table body. Instead of `newRow = table.insertRow(table.rows.length)`, you use `newRow = fragment.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'))`

Answer (score 1):

You won't win much here.

Given that everything is done synchronously it's basically just the same action as if you were using a `DocumentFragment` already.
And actually, you rarely win much in using `DocumentFragment` objects rather than dealing with the DOM directly (sometimes you even lose by doing so). The perfs boost from it is basically a myth from a decade ago. The browser just has to do the same things anyway when you [append](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-node-insert) the fragment*.

In some engines you may win by letting the parser deal with it entirely, i.e. by passing it an HTML markup trough `.insertAdjacentHTML()` or even `.innerHTML`. That should get the best built-in optimizations. Just beware you shouldn't pass untrusted data in there as you'd be at risk of XSS attacks.

But the best in such a case is to not render all the cells in one call.
Instead use either pagination, or a scroll-based lazy-rendering.

---

Ps: Here is a [twitter thread](https://twitter.com/jaffathecake/status/1552242561313546241) from Jake Archibald about this very misconception with some benchmarks.

---

<sup>* The only notable difference would be if you had an `MutationObserver` looking at the parent node, triggering one heavy action per MutationRecord, since you'd get them all separated instead of a single one in the case of a fragment.</sup>

Comment: Yep, you are right. I implemented some of the other suggestions and I could not notice any difference. Though, I was not using jsperf or anything like that, just going by eye. When you're in the multiple-second range, that's usually good enough. I will look into your other suggestions, thank you.